# Make a flat buffer using simple features st_buffer

Tags: r, buffer, r-sf

Is it possible to make a "flat" buffer around lines in the same way as gbuffer work:

```
 buf_t <- gBuffer(py,capStyle="FLAT", width=py$width, byid=T)
```

for sf it works with round buffers, but I cannot find information on flat buffers:

```
buf_sf <- st_buffer(st_as_sf(py2),dist = py$width, SomeWayToMakeItFlat? = T)
```

Comment: currently, it doesn't provide this option.

Comment: Where would be the correct place to wish for such a function?

Comment: You could raise it as an issue (as of: feature request) on the github sf site.

Comment: This has now been implemented in sf::st_buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sf has implemented this now.

```
buf_sf <- st_buffer(st_as_sf(py2),dist = py$width, endCapStyle = 'FLAT')
```