# Make a flat buffer using terra::buffer

Tags: r, buffer, terra

Is it possible to make a "flat" buffer around lines in the same way as st_buffer work:

```
buf_sf <- st_buffer(st_as_sf(py2),dist = py2$width, endCapStyle = 'FLAT')
```

for terra it works with round buffers, but I cannot find information on flat buffers:

```
terra_buffer <- py2|>
  vect() |>
  buffer(width = py2$width, SomeWayToMakeItFlat? = "T")
  st_as_sf()
```

[Make a flat buffer using simple features st_buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223614/make-a-flat-buffer-using-simple-features-st-buffer)

Comment: See `?terra::buffer`